# How To Update Related Entities with EF6

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have in my DB a record of a Course with some Students.

```
Course Table 
Id | Name

Student Table
Id | Name | CourseId
```

So, for example, I could have the Course "1 (Maths)" that contains 5 students, "Andy, Carl, Bob, Mary, Harry"

In My model I have this:

```
public class Course
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Student> Student { get; set; }
}
```

When I save a new Course with a list of students, I use this code and all works fine. The course is saved in DB and all students are created with him.

```
public TEntity Add(TEntity entity)
{
    this.context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
    this.context.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
    this.EntitySet.Add(entity);
    this.context.SaveChanges();
}
```

But when I need modify the Student's list, I modify it from code, but in DB the  new relations aren't updated. I use this code for Update:

```
public TEntity Edit(TEntity entity)
{
    this.context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
    this.context.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;

    this.EntitySet.Attach(entity);
    this.context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    this.context.SaveChanges();
}
```

So, my question is:

How can I Update the student's list in DB with an Update of Entity Framework when I change the list of the Course.

Thanks a lot

**EDIT 1**

This is an example.

```
// Params (Id, Name, Students)
Course maths = new Course(1, "Maths", "Andy, Carl, Bob, Mary, Harry");

this.Add(maths);
//In DB is created the Course and the students with DB relation. No problem.

maths.Students = new List<Student>();
maths.Students.Add("Igor");
maths.Students.Add("Carl");
maths.Students.Add("Sam");
maths.Students.Add("Dante");

this.Edit(maths);
//In DB is updated the maths Course register, but the Student's list is not updated.
```

Comment: Just curious why you have a one to many relationship for classes and students instead of many to many.

Comment: The code for the update does not show what is actually done with `entity`, can you post that?

Comment: @juharr Sure, but I invented an easy and fast example for ask the question. The real problem is more complicated.

Comment: @PeterBons I update the question. Thanks

Comment: The trick is to ADD the `maths` entity to the context, then set its state to `Modifed`. Using Add will set the state of all the entities in  a graph to `Added` (and in this way the students will be added).